# How to trigger the azure devops build pipeline using azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I am trying to setup a slack integration to trigger the azure build pipeline using azure logic app.

I have completed the setup for slack command to point to logic app http request endpoint url. however i am unable to extract the parameter value passed with slack command as argument and set that as parameter to pass it to queue a build (azure devops)

Slack command:

```
/trigger-build ansible_verbosity=2 pa__name=max6 pa__tag=deploy pa_deployment_override=true version=5.8.3
```

Below are the HTTP request received output

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json,*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip,deflate",
        "Host": "prod-54.southeastasia.logic.azure.com",
        "User-Agent": "Slackbot,1.0,(+https://api.slack.com/robots)",
        "X-Slack-Signature": "v0=52408903d16175bc6a3e2eca1dd03a720b50adfb1bd3abac79fc49c9f6e8e256",
        "X-Slack-Request-Timestamp": "1686864764",
        "Content-Length": "554",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    "body": {
        "$content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "$content": "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",
        "$formdata": [
            {
                "key": "token",
                "value": "8Iwv6tfBznjxIwp0KtFY7uKz"
            },
            {
                "key": "team_id",
                "value": "T05B1FZKTFV"
            },
            {
                "key": "team_domain",
                "value": "learnazurecloudcoin"
            },
            {
                "key": "channel_id",
                "value": "C05BRB43Y9W"
            },
            {
                "key": "channel_name",
                "value": "automation"
            },
            {
                "key": "user_id",
                "value": "U05BRAZLN56"
            },
            {
                "key": "user_name",
                "value": "syed.aman"
            },
            {
                "key": "command",
                "value": "/trigger-build"
            },
            {
                "key": "text",
                "value": "ansible_verbosity=2 pa_internal_name=max6 pa_deploy_tag=deploy pa_deployment_patch_override=true version=5.8.3"
            },
            {
                "key": "api_app_id",
                "value": "A05B1N57F8A"
            },
            {
                "key": "is_enterprise_install",
                "value": "false"
            },
            {
                "key": "response_url",
                "value": "https://hooks.slack.com/commands/T05B1FZKTFV/5435201370018/OixlbQ3QmoRozhCMss0gkSb9"
            },
            {
                "key": "trigger_id",
                "value": "5432262432197.5375543673539.03e9a05b9b0a9e95c0e4c12a8a7fc6fc"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The parameters which I had passed are stored as "text".

```
{
                "key": "text",
                "value": "ansible_verbosity=2 pa_internal_name=max6 pa_deploy_tag=deploy pa_deployment_patch_override=true version=5.8.3"
            },
```

Need Help in extracting the values and setting it as a parameters to pass it to queue a build (azure devops)

Comment: So with this ... "I am unable to extract the parameter value passed with slack command as argument and set that as parameter to pass it to queue a build (azure devops)" ... what is the problem?